# How to get a screen saver working in Java

Tags: java, spring

I recently completed a Java course from caveofprogramming.com. It was a great course, and I learned a lot. I am trying to create a screen saver program in Java, but my graphic that is suppose to float around the screen just flicks in the middle of the screen.

Here is what I have so far:

```
/**
  * Phoenix Hospitality Management System (PHMS)
  * PHMS 001 - TME Protector
  * Screen Protector Program
  * Copyright (C) 2021 By Troy Marker Enterprises
  * All Right Reserved
  * 
  * NOTICE: This program was created for use of the Phoenix Hospitality Management                   System (PHMS). Any use outside of the PHMS
  * is strictly prohibited. * 
  */

  package view;

  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
  import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
  import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
  import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
  import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
  import java.io.IOException;

  import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
  import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.Timer;
  
  import view.PhoenixColors;

  /**
   * Main screen protector class;
   * Called by the App Controller
   * 
   * @author Troy L. Marker
   *
   */
  public class Protect extends JFrame implements KeyListener, MouseMotionListener, ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3655698826064710315L;
    private JLabel logo;
    private Timer timer;
    private double speed = 10.0;
    private double xLoc;
    private double yLoc;
    private int xDirectionLogo = 1;
    private int yDirectionLogo = 1;
    
    public Protect() {
        getContentPane().setBackground(PhoenixColors.BLACK);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        setUndecorated(true);
        timer = new Timer(20, this);
        BufferedImage TMELogo = null;
        try {
            TMELogo = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/TMELogo.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(TMELogo));
        add(logo);

        setVisible(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        timer.start();
    }
  
    private void update() {
        xLoc += xDirectionLogo * speed;
        yLoc += yDirectionLogo * speed;
        
        if (xLoc < 0) {
            xDirectionLogo = 1;
            xLoc = 1;
        } else if (xLoc > getWidth() - logo.getWidth()) {
            xDirectionLogo = -1;
            xLoc = getWidth() - logo.getWidth();
        }
        if (yLoc < 0) {
            yDirectionLogo = 1;
            yLoc = 1;
        } else if(yLoc > getHeight() - logo.getHeight()) {
            yDirectionLogo = -1;
            yLoc = getHeight() - logo.getHeight();
        }
        logo.setLocation((int)xLoc, (int)yLoc);
        repaint();
        System.out.println("xLoc, yLoc: "+ xLoc + ", " + yLoc);
    
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }
  
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
  
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    }
  
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
        
    }
  
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        update();
    }
  }
```

The update method is what I use to adjust the position of the image every 20 milliseconds. What am I missing?

### Addendum

In response to Stephen's comment, I feel I need to clarify what I am doing. I am designing a computer system for the hospitality industry. I am creating my own Linux system using Linux From Scratch. I want a Java based screen saver because that is the language I am planning to write the software in.

Java may not be the best language to create this system in, but I like the fact the it is a cross platform language due to the JVM.

Comment: (Comment: I think you would be better off using a screen saver provided via your user's base operating system.  An dynamic screen saver running in a JVM is going to consume a lot more memory, CPU, electricity ... coal.)

Comment: Don't create "God" applications. Your Swing application should not be a `JFrame` that does everything. Instead, breakdown your app into components responsible for specific things. For example, your Frame (app) class should be just the container for the contents. You could then create classes (i.e. `JPanel`) responsible for displaying the contents. All those listeners should be used by your panel (or some other component) and not your frame.

Comment: I also noticed you don't have any code to handle closing your frame. Which means that, when you click the "X" button in the corner, your frame will be dismissed but the application will continue to run in the background. This is not good.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the JLabel is added as the only content of the JFrame, so it is resized to be the full size of the JFrame. I printed out size on my machine and the `JFrame`'s `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` return 1536x864 while the `JLabel`'s `logo.getWidth()` and `logo.getHeight()` are also 1536x864.

You might be able to control the size of the `JLabel`, but it seems to me that it would be easier to simple add a `JPanel` to your layout and override its `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method to call `super.paintComponent(g);` and then just draw the `BufferedImage` wherever you want within it.

Answer (score 0):

Commit this code to memory (or save it somewhere so you could reuse this pattern). This is the correct way to implement the main application frame for a Swing application.

```
public class FrameDemo {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Basic Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // To REALLY close your app
 
        JPanel emptyPanel = new JPanel();
        emptyPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(emptyPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Schedule your app to run in the Event Dispatcher Thread
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

After you do this, modify this code following @David Conrad's advice. Don't forget to create a custom class for your panel and add the event handlers where they belong.